# Firebase realtime database invalid database location error

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I have a database with the following structure. root -> users -> info -> userID. info has four thousand childs. I get an error when I try to view the rows from the browser.  error: invalid database location.

Clicking load more gives an error :

[image]

error page:
[image]

Is there a problem with my database? I've been looking since yesterday and couldn't find a wrong line.

Comment: This might be a bug in the Firebase console itself...

Comment: *firebaser here* As Martin says that sounds unexpected.  Before declaring it a bug though, can you try disabling any browser extensions you may have, and possibly also try loading the same in another browser. If the problem persists, please [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting - and so that they can alert the engineering team if this is indeed an bug in the console.